# instead of using cloudSQL we will use compute engine to install other database server

Tags: database, server, cloud, google-compute-engine, lan

I would like ask if a created google compute engine (vm) can be part of our local area network in our site and serves as our database server where every client can connect through our internet server?

instead of using cloudSQL we will use compute engine to install other database server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assign a GCE VM to directly have an IP address from your local network, but if you run your own DNS in your network, you could add an entry to point your database server name at the Google IP, and you could configure routes on your network to go through your Internet server to get to that address. Alternately, if you have VPN IPSEC hardware at your site, you could use [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview) to setup a tunnel from your site to your GCE project.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestion paul